# Run a jar file without JDK installed

Tags: java, jar

is there any way to run a jar file without JDK installed ?

for example convert jar file to exe or put the jdk or jre into the jar file or something like this...

Comment: There seems to be some solutions here that don't require the JRE or JDK: [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014187/can-we-run-an-java-app-in-a-system-without-jre)

Answer (score 1):

JRE is a must. JDK is not a necessity.