# Why has an application written in a language JAVA not working on Windows only install JDK?

Tags: java

Why can't I run a Java application without a JDK installed?
Is there a way to run a Java program on Windows without the JDK?

Comment: This is probably a better dup link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488194/run-a-jar-file-without-jdk-installed

Comment: @StephenC Linking to a question that hasn"t been answered seems weird to me :/

Comment: It has been answered.  "JRE is a must. JDK is not a necessity."  But can you suggest a better one?

Answer (score 2):

To run a java programm you don't need the JDK installed. You only need an installed JRE.

Comment: JRE only don't  run if the program .exe

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaking JRE and JDK, but if you're asking "Can I run a java program (a .jar) on windows without installing Java", then the answer is "No, you can't".

JRE stands for "Java Runtime Environnement", it's the VM Java uses to lauch and execute your program. If you don't have a JRE installed you **cannot** launch a java program.

Comment: I'm talking about running the java application of Windows without downloading anything like any other Windows program.

Comment: @MohammedHamdy You can't run a java application without installing a JRE. It's not possible. It's like trying to use Firefox without installing it before.

Comment: Is the software available for Windows are written in any language ?? Such as media palyer classic

Comment: @MohammedHamdy There is a big difference between an executable for windows (a .exe) and a java executable (a .jar). If you're looking to create a .exe file, you should modify your question.

Comment: exe. file. It also  not works only in the presence of JDK

Answer (score 0):

Java is compiled to a *system independent byte code*.

There must be a *System dependent byte code interpreter* on the target machine to execute the Java program.