# Standalone Programs developed in Java

Tags: java, runtime-environment

There are stand-alone programs which can be executed e.g. under Windows, of which the developers state that they wrote the program "using the Java programming language".
I am not a Software developer or a programmer, but through some basic programming courses in school and at university I was taught that Java Programms can only be run in a Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

**So what I am asking is:** how can I run these programs written in Java on my computer, without having any JRE?

**A follow-up question would be:** How is this step technically performed, to create such a program that does not need a JRE for running from Java code?

**Please note:** I am not questioning the concept of the JRE as a whole. It *does* make sence to me to use this concept, to have platform independent programs by using a runtime environment.
My question solely is about how is this stand-alone solution made possible, not about its convenience, or its meaningfulness. It is obviously done for whatever reasons, and I want to know how.

Comment: I guess those programs are being shipped with bundled JRE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371535/running-java-without-installing-jre

Comment: I have created a list of ways to [deploy Java applications here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453369/i-have-never-seen-a-software-be-released-as-jar-so-how-can-i-make-a-software-be/1453477#1453477). This includes ways to deploy as "JVM-less" executables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Ship JRE with your application. Then application will use it for execution. There are also some [Compilers](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) for this purpose. 
Read this question:
[running a java program as an exe in windows without JRE installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332548/running-a-java-program-as-an-exe-in-windows-without-jre-installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excelsior JET compiler for that purpose.It will convert your java application to .exe

See [Excelsior](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) for more information on this.