# How to create a standalone application using JavaFX 11 (Modular)?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-platform-module-system, openjfx

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse) and using `openjdk 11.0.2` and `javafx-sdk-11.0.2`.
I've imported the *maven* project in Eclipse. The project actually compiles and packages just fine. It also created the jar file  in /target directory.
The problem is, I want to export a **single executable** for my application which **also embeds the necessary JRE in itself** (so there would be no need to have a JRE installed on the target machine).
  Here is the actual [project](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/Eclipse/Modular/Maven) .

How can I automate the generation of the standalone executable in maven? I want a single exe if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at [How to deploy a JavaFX 11 Desktop application with a JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53453212/9662601)?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp It seems the tool I need is javapackager but it was removed from JDK 11 and now it is released experimentally

Comment: Alternatively look at installer generators, creating a setup.exe or such. Also the migration to Java 17 would be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studying [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332548/1374678) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7071133/1374678) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33956697/1374678) on SO, I think there is no way to produce a single EXE that includes the JRE. However, the tools mentioned can produce an EXE that can be put *alongside* a "jre" directory.

Using the [JavaPackager](https://github.com/fvarrui/JavaPackager) Maven plugin, this can actually be achieved quite easily, simply by adding something like this in your POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.fvarrui</groupId>
    <artifactId>javapackager</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                <bundleJre>true</bundleJre>
                <platform>windows</platform>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Running `mvn package` will generate a directory inside "target" that contains the EXE, a "jre" directory and a "libs" directory. The plugin can also generate an installer file.

Obviously, for different platforms you need to adjust the config, but I tested this on Windows with JDK 16 and 17, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: If you really want to create a single standalone EXE it can be done with Gluons tool chain. https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_windows

Comment: @mipa can the gluons plugin be used to make an installable version of the JavaFX application in windows ? (like JPackage)

Comment: No, it just creates the EXE but I think you can then create an installer with other tools. I am not so familiar with Windows.